# why do I get an error when building my pakage?

Tags: opencv, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using ubuntu 13.04 an I have created a package using **catkin_create_pkg tutorial_opencv image_transport roscpp std_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge uvc_camera**.There is c++ program in my package called **DisplayImage**.The pkg is in my catkin workspace .When I built it I had an  error 
**CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "opencv2" with any

of the following names:

opencv2Config.cmake 

opencv2-config.cmake**

I included in the CMakelist.txt

" FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS}<br>
${catkin_LIBRARIES})"

Here is the full content of my **CMakelist.txt** plus the output of "**VERBOSE=1 catkin_make -j1** "
https://gist.github.com/Leyonce/9731649
I am supposing the problem has to do with the fact that thoses files don't exsit in the opencv2 package and In my utmost arrogant opinion they don't exist at all.What I see is the **OpenCvConfig.cmake** file and the **OpenCVConfig-version.cmake** file 
in the OPENCV directory which is supposed to be a library.
Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143141/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-building-my-pakage?/) by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-23**:
the link to the gist is dead

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-23**:
I've made a new one.Thanks for your patience.I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

OpenCV is no longer packed inside ROS, instead now it is a system dependency. I guess that the information on the tutorials that you mention is outdated. You should remove all references to *opencv2* in your CMakeList.txt.

The correct way to link your node to opencv is by adding the following to CMakeList.txt :

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(my_cool_node src/my_cool_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_cool_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

I hope this helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-30**:
@Martin, Thanks.Could you point me to the where I can find the updated info?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-03-31**:
Hi Leonce, I am glad the answer was useful. You can find the updated information here: http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-04-01**:
Thanks @Martin but I think there's an error in the link,the page doesn't exist yet.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-04-01**:
Sorry, I don't know why there was a "</p>" attached to the end of the link... just remove it and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add an executable or library called `my_target`? If not, having a statement like `target_link_libraries(my_target ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})` does not make sense. This seems to be your cmake error.

I would be best if you edit your question to provide the full contents of your CMakeLists.txt and the full output of `VERBOSE=1 catkin_make -j1` (don't use rosmake with a catkin package).

**Edit:**

For sure the following line should be removed: https://gist.github.com/Leyonce/9731649#file-cmakelist-L11

And it would be good to move line https://gist.github.com/Leyonce/9731649#file-cmakelist-L9 to around line 105 to keep things in order.

You are not building any executables or libraries. What is your package supposed to build?

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-23**:
yes I thought so too but I was just following the tutorials.I don't know yet how to add that library.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-23**:
If you need any further help, please edit your question to provide the information I asked for. Thanks

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-23**:
If it is lengthy, put the files/output on pastebin.com or gist.github.com and post the links.

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-23**:
?? Well I haven't placed any .cpp file in my src file. I sought to build the tutorial_opencv package i guess.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-28**:
Ok, do the changes and the package should build. But since it is an empty package not much will happen when you build it. What is your goal with this package?

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-30**:
Thanks.I've done the changes.That solved the problem due to the target library but not that due to the package configuration files.The package did not build.